# Equality of irrational numbers and the need for a proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This seems obvious to me, but do we need a formal proof to establish this is always true?

Let $x$ and $y$ be irrational numbers with decimal representations

$x = 0.x_1x_2x_3 \dots$

$y = 0.y_1y_2y_3 \dots$

If $x_n = y_n$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Can we then infer that $x = y$ ?

Comment: What's your definition of a real number?

Comment: If the real numbers have been defined by Dedekind cuts, say, then certainly this requires proof.

Comment: As you see this is not a set theory problem.  You will better responses tagging your question to calculus.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps it seems obvious to you because the symbols would be identical. But a real number is not a symbol, it is an abstract mathematical quantity.

So if you are defining the real numbers by a construction (Dedekind cuts; or equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences of rational numbers), or if on the other hand you are starting from axioms (the axioms for a complete ordered field), there is indeed something to prove.

What a decimal number really is, is just a shortand for a certain infinite series:
$$0.x_1x_2x_3\cdots = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x_n}{10^n}
$$
So you will need at some point to prove a theorem which says that if an infinite series converges then the number it converges to is unique.

Comment: Isn’t your last paragraph the very core of the question?

Comment: It is. Given the tag, I thought it best to write a set-up as well.

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: if you want to prove something basic like this, it means that you allow yourself only **very** elementary tools, that are so elementary that they are in fact extremely abstract and make the proof not so easy to grasp.

A real number is an *equivalence class of Cauchy sequences of rational numbers*, under the equivalence relation $$(u_n)\sim (v_n)\Longleftrightarrow \lim_{n\to \infty} (u_n-v_n)=0$$

In your case by definition $x$ is the class of the Cauchy sequence of rationals $(u_n=0.x_1x_2\ldots x_n)$ and $y$ is the class of the *same* sequence, therefore the limit of the difference is $0$ and $x=y$.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that if we accept the axiom of extensionality then we have the proof.

Then the only question is "can we convert a decimal expansion into a set?"

Let Set $A = \{ \frac{x_1}{10},\frac{x_2}{100},\frac{x_3}{1000} \dots \}  $

and Set $B = \{ \frac{y_1}{10},\frac{y_2}{100},\frac{y_3}{1000} \dots \}  $

Then by the axiom of extensionality https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_extensionality

we can say the two sets are the same and the two decimal terms are also the same.